# EF 4 Count() options performance

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

What is the most performant way to count items on a table using EF 4.1?

```
this.context.MyTable.Count(x.idTenant == 5);
```

or

```
 this.context.MyTable.Where(x.idTenant == 5).Count();
```

Any other way to Count entities in a table, being it more performant?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer, but your two examples would must likely create the same expression tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890381/how-to-count-rows-within-entityframework-without-loading-contents

Comment: @JoeTuskan, Reshaper suggested the first one, but I don't know if it is just another way to write it or there is a performance gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output from Linq, the expressions are equal in the SQL they generate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[idTenant] = @p0
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying this in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) shows the sql generated to be the same:

```
var r1 = Users.Count(u => u.JurisdictionId == 5).Dump();    
var r2 = Users.Where(u => u.JurisdictionId == 5).Count().Dump();
```

and the sql generated:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [System].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 5 = [Extent1].[JurisdictionId]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [System].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 5 = [Extent1].[JurisdictionId]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

This is using EF 4.2, but this should be the same in 4.1.

Comment: +1 I'd then wager to say, the first one would run *slightly* faster with one less method call.