# Entity Framework 5 - Loads all rows on count

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a very big table with more then one million rows.

Simple:

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.Streets = new HashSet<Streets>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Street
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to get the total count of streets in a country I can do

```
context.CountryStreets.Count(v=>v.CountryId == X)
```

EF gives you an easy method to access the related table with lazy loading:

```
Country.Streets.Count()
```

This method is very nice and easy but... For some reason it's loading the total related table.

Why? And how can I change this behavior?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why?

   Because it is not made for this purpose.
2. And how can I change this behavior?

   You really can't - only if you start to mess around with the Expression Provider.

**To Note:**

If we retrieve 50 records and on each row we do 'count', we will have more than 50(!) requests to MSSQL , as a result - very bad performance.

The best solution is to do something like this:

```
ct.Country.Select(v => new { Country = v, TotalStreets = v.Streets.Count() });
```

Please not that there is only one request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two links, they may help with your issue:

[How to COUNT rows within EntityFramework without loading contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890381/how-to-count-rows-within-entityframework-without-loading-contents)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: 1. This I showed in my post. 2. Really ugly - Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Query().Count(); - Is there a nice way?