# what is the best way to check that there are no rows in a table in entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

what is the best way to check that there are no rows in a table in  entity framework?

I have this piece of code

```
context.users.Count() ==0
```

but I think that it could be expensive to count the rows in a table to check if there are rows in the table or not, so is there any other way to do this.

Comment: May be your can find answer from this Post.

[How to COUNT rows within EntityFramework without loading contents?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890381/how-to-count-rows-within-entityframework-without-loading-contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Take(1).Count()`.

To check if no row exists check the count like this.

```
if (context.users.Take(1).Count() == 0)
{
// do something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, the must readable way is using `context.users.Any()`.Which, EF translates it to:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[users] AS [Extent1]
  )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
  FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```